# Change order of strata in table

Tags: r, gtsummary, gt

Trying to change the order of the cyl groups within the strata to 6 Cylinder, 4 Cylinder, 8 Cylinder.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

tbl <- 
  mtcars %>%
  select(am, cyl, mpg, hp) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    cyl = paste(cyl, "Cylinder"),
    am = factor(am, labels = c("Automatic", "Manual"))
  ) %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = cyl,
    ~.x %>%
      tbl_summary(
        by = am,
        type = where(is.numeric) ~ "continuous"
      ) %>%
      modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**")
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

To change the order of a categorical variable, change it to a factor, and specify the order in the `levels` part as shown below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

tbl <- 
  mtcars %>%
  select(am, cyl, mpg, hp) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    cyl = paste(cyl, "Cylinder"),
    am = factor(am, labels = c("Automatic", "Manual")),
    cyl = factor(cyl, levels = c("8 Cylinder", "6 Cylinder", "4 Cylinder"))
  ) %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = cyl,
    ~.x %>%
      tbl_summary(
        by = am,
        type = where(is.numeric) ~ "continuous"
      ) %>%
      modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**")
  )
tbl
```

[image: gtsummary table]